# Puppeteer installation for different operating system

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, cicd

In my CI/CD environment I use linux to build my application.
However, my node.js application runs on a windows server.

Here is the problem: Executing npm install on a linux system will install the linux chormium version for puppeteer. When this resulting files (with the node_modules) are executed on a windows system the necessary chromium version is missing.

How can this be solved? I only found one related question, which has not been answered adequately. None of the solutions work.
[Puppeteer: Download Chromium for different platforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47757720/puppeteer-download-chromium-for-different-platforms)

Comment: Can you rephrase and clarify _When this build is executed on a windows system the necessary chromium version is missing_?

Comment: I tried to paraphrase it. I mean the resulting files after executing the "npm install" on the linux system. Then the node_modules are added to my project. When I copy my whole project, including those node_modules to a windows instance afterwards, it will not include the necessary windows chromium instance but only the linux chromium instance.

Comment: Related — https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62359227/npm-ci-cross-platform-reliability — no solutions but there are comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing file `package-lock.json` on Windows before `$ npm install`.

It's typically better to run `npm install` on the target runtime environment to ensure that the platform-specific packages are downloaded/built appropriately.

> Apart from that, `npm install` is executed on the linux system in the ci/cd environment.

Because you're not running `npm install` on Windows, consider downloading Chromium separately on Windows and setting `PUPPETEER_EXECUTABLE_PATH` (see [environment variables](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v13.0.0/docs/api.md#environment-variables)).

Comment: There is no package-lock.json file at the time when `npm install` is executed. Apart from that, `npm install` is executed on the linux system in the ci/cd environment.